# Is there any collapsible flex container that can handle dynamic content that works when pre-collapsed?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, resize

Do you know any collapsible flex container that can handle dynamic content that works when pre-collapsed?

I tried the CollapsiblePanel component by Arc90 for Flex, but it did not work when pre-collapsed.

If I have a VBox inside the panel, and I set the "collapsed" property of the CollapsiblePanel to true, the size of the CollapsiblePanel cannot be restored. It seems like this is what is happening:

1. The CollapsiblePanel's collapsed property is pre-set to true in the MXML markup.
2. The VBox auto-adjusts its height to 0 since the CollapsiblePanel is collapsed.
3. When the CollapsiblePanel's collapsed property changes to false (i.e., it is expanded by the user), the VBox does not expand itself because its parent's content area is 0.
4. Therefore the CollapsiblePanel remains at the same height because its content's height is 0.
5. Therefore...

**Note: This occurs only when the CollapsiblePanel is pre-collapsed, as seen in the markup below.**

I've already tried this (didn't work):

```
    <containers:CollapsiblePanel minimize="pnl_minimize(event)" 
restore="pnl_restore(event)" height="100%" width="100%" collapsed="true">
    <mx:VBox width="100%" height="100%" verticalGap="0">
       <mx:LinkButton id="lnkSales1" label="Sales 1" />
       <mx:LinkButton id="lnkSales2" label="Sales 2" />
    </mx:VBox>
    </containers:CollapsiblePanel>

 private function pnl_restore(event:Event):void
{
    var objPanel:CollapsiblePanel = event.target as CollapsiblePanel;
    var objChildArray:Array = objPanel.getChildren();
    for each (var obj:Object in objChildArray)
    {
       obj.invalidateSize();
    }
    objPanel.invalidateSize();
}
```

Is there anyone who has succeeded in doing something like this? What component did you use?

Comment: This code seems to be working for me. Try also giving the CollapsiblePanel and the VBox a height dimension. such as height="100%" so it can restore to that size

Comment: @[Ian T] I added the height="100%" but it didn't have any effect. Are you also pre-collapsing the CollapsiblePanel in the MXML when the module is loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got a solution, though it's a bit of a workaround. I allow all the panels to be loaded and then collapse them programmatically instead of pre-collapsing them in the markup. This way their size is already computed and can be restored without any issues when the user restores them.

Does anyone have a better solution?